# How to add a command button in excel that takes data from 8 different cells and puts them in another sheet in a row?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in excel cells D4, D9, D14, D20, D25, G3, H2 and I2. Everytime, I have different data in all the cells and when I click the command update button, I want the data to be transferred over in 'sheet 2' in a row.

I know I have to use a macro and all the places online I have looked have answers related to a range of cells like from A2:A12 but not for several specific cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy them individually or use an array.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim vals As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'resize vals to hold all 8 values in a single row
        ReDim vals(1 To 1, 1 To 8)

        'put the values into an array
        vals(1, 1) = .Range("D4").Value
        vals(1, 2) = .Range("D9").Value
        vals(1, 3) = .Range("D14").Value
        vals(1, 4) = .Range("D20").Value
        vals(1, 5) = .Range("D25").Value
        vals(1, 6) = .Range("G3").Value
        vals(1, 7) = .Range("H2").Value
        vals(1, 8) = .Range("I2").Value

    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")

        'find next available row in sheet2
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            'resize the target and insert vals
            .Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*You may try this VBA macro to copy certain cells value from Sheet to another.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, cls

cls = Array("D4", "D9", "D14", "D20", "D25", "G3", "H2", "I2")

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(2, .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)

    For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
    .Cells(LR, i + [A1].Column).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cls(i)).Value
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- In above code `Sheet1` has source data and `Sheet2` is destination sheet.
- `WorksheetFunction.Max(2,` , here `2` sets *Row 2 in destination Sheet*, and is editable.

---

- Since you are handling a few cells then another method should,

  ```
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
  ```

*You may add other cells also.*

Comment: What's the purpose of `WorksheetFunction.Max`? The `.End(xlUp).Row + 1` method will always produce a row number of 2 or more even if there is no column header label in row 1.

Comment: @Jeeped,,, nice observation,, its as precaution since OP has not mentioned that has headers or not ! And every click will copy next to previous row or in new row.